# Голоса животных

Tags: этимология

Мяу — мяукать, кукареку — кукарекать, но почему лошадь — ржет, а собака — лает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лингвистическая разница между словами   заключается в разнице отношений между планом выражения и планом содержания.
План выражения ( звучание) слов кукарекать и кукареку, мяукать и мяу совпадает , физически изображает их содержание.Звукоподражание мотивирует словообразование глагола. Звучание слов ржать, лаять связано с их содержанием условной (произвольной) связью.
Лаять - издавать лай (что такое лай, мы знаем),если бы словообразование пошло по пути мотивирования звукоподражанием,получилось бы гавкать, что в русском языке тоже есть, но имеет стилистич. помету простореч. То же самое и о ржании. Ржать - издавать специфический звук, отдалённо похожий на "и-го-го","игогокать" - просторечие, неприятное созвучие, потому словообразование не воспользовалось этой моделью для общеупотребительного слова.

Answer (score 3):

[@Saito](/users/48/saito), по-моему, так и не понял, почему в его вопросенет логики. Может, так будет понятнее?

*Мяу — мяукать, кукареку — кукарекать, но почему иго-го — ржать, а гав-гав — лаять?*

Comment: Ну, так можно не только лаять, но еще и именно гавкать!

Comment: Вот при такой постановке вопроса всё становится понятным.

Comment: Да есть там "логика". Вполне нормальная, хотя логика требуется обычно как раз в ответе, а не в вопросе. К чемы вы тут придрались, остаётся загадкой.

Первые два примера пострены на ьпрямых звукоподрожательных словах, два последних - не на них.ю Автор и спрашивает, почему так. даже слово "почему", обычно совершенно неуместное в вопросах о языке хдесь выглядит нормальным, т.к. вопрос касается этимологии.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятная у вас логика. Кошка (а не *"мяу"*) мяукает, петух (а не *"кукареку"*) кукарекает, лошадь ржет, а собака лает.

> Ржать происходит от др.-русск. ръзати,
> ръжу, сербск.-церк.-слав. ръзати,
> ст.-слав. ръжѫ (др.-греч. χρεμετίζω).
> Ср.: укр. ржа́ти, ржу, iржати, белор.
> ржаць, iржа́ць, сербохорв. р̏зати,
> р̏же̑м, словенск. rzáti, rzȃm, ŕžem,
> чешск. rzát, ržáti, словацк. hržаt᾽,
> hrzаt᾽, еrdžаt᾽, польск. rżać, rżeć.
> Праслав. *rъzati,* rъžǫ, *rъžеši (из*
> rъzi̯ǫ) **родственно греч. ἐρυγόντα вин. ед. «ревущий», ἐρύγμηλος — то же,
> ἐρυγήτωρ ̇ βοητής (Гесихий), лат.
> rūgiō, -īrе «реветь», ср.-ирл. rucht
> «рёв, вой».** Сюда же, вероятно,
> относится и название реки Ржать, в
> [бывш.] Смол. губ. Ср. также рыга́ть,
> рыча́ть. Следует отделять это слово от
> лит. rūgóti «обижаться», которое
> заимств. из русск. руга́ть.

Жирным выделил то, почему лошади ржут. Происходит от латинского *"реветь"*.

---

> Лай происходит от др.-русск. лаи "брань, ссора, оскорбление".

Видимо, так как лай собак не очень доброжелатен его назвали лаем.

*Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера*

Comment: >Непонятная у вас логика. Кошка (а не "мяу") мяукает, петух (а не "кукареку") кукарекает, лошадь ржет, а собака лает.  

Поясните, пожалуйста, что вам не понравилось в логике?!

>Жирным выделил то, почему лошади ржут. 

-?! И почему?   

>Происходит от латинского "реветь".   

Вряд ли. Как может древнеславянская основа происходить от латинской?!

Comment: Праславяне построили Рим, ну а дальше пошло-поехало.

Comment: @behemothus, логика мне не понравилась в том, что вначале написаны существительные и однокоренные глаголы, а потом название животного и выполняемое им действие.     
Лошади ржут потому, что издают звук, похожий на рёв, от которого и пришло на русь слово *"ржать"*.
Если не из латинского, то я не знаю, что значит *"лат."* у Фасмера.

Comment: >вначале написаны существительные и однокоренные глаголы...  
  
Надо наоборот?   
  
>что значит "лат." у Фасмера.  
  
"лат" - значит латинское. Без "из".  
  
>Лошади ржут потому, что издают звук, похожий на рёв    
  
Да. Но об этом нет ни слова в выделенной вами части текста  
  
>которого и пришло на русь слово "ржать".    
  
Да не приходило ничего на Русь. Если морф присутсует одновременно в греческом, латинском и германо-балто-славяснких, но этот морф _**праиндоевропейский**_.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, придется сформулировать ясный ответ на основании сказанного другими.

~1. "Мяукать" от "мяу" и "кукарекать" от "кукареку" построены на звукоподражательных "мяу" и "кукареку", но общего правила на этот счет не существует; такие слова, обозначающие "звуковые" действия животных могут образовываться не только от прямых звукоподражаний.

~2. Ржать, лаять, блеять, мычать и проч. построены на другой модели, в основу положено не прямое звукоgодражание, а морф, обозначающий (или обозначавший ранее) такие звуки в целом.

~3. Этимологию слов лаять и ржать здесь приводили.

Answer (score 0):

Лошадь — ржет, а собака — лает, потому что кошка мяукает, а петух кукарекает. Исходя из вопроса, как-то так...

Comment: "И такая дребедень целый день...
То тюлень позвонит, то олень." К.И.Ч.